# How to scan storage devices for recovering deleted files?

Tags: android, data-recovery

I have seen apps like DiskDigger and Hexamob Recovery, which scan storage devices and allow you to recover deleted files. I was wondering if this can be done via the Android SDK, or does it require use of something else like Android NDK? Either way, can someone point me in the right direction on how this can be done? I would like to make my own implementation.

Note: This question is similar in nature to [Android: deleted file(s) and message(s) recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205039/android-deleted-files-and-messages-recovery), but more general about what API should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Android is running on linux, and as such, you would have to use the posix libs or the standard C ones. This is independent from android, except that you need to use NDK to integrate that functionality in your app. AFAIK, there's no droid-specific api to do that. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571596/low-level-disk-operations-in-linux-for-c) a thread that might get you going.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does anyone care to add to this answer some example code using posix libs or standard C library that would help someone like me to get started? Also, I'd be very interested to hear from someone with experience doing something similar on Android (although Android is based on Linux, there can sometimes be difficulties porting Linux libraries to Android)....